# Is it possible to reference scope in angularjs like in c#?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem in referencing angularjs scopes like in c# or c++.

Here is the scenario:

I have a code like this in HTML.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right myDropdown" role="menu" style="border-radius:0">
  <li data-ng-repeat="year in YearList"><a data-ng-click="SetYear(year,summer1)">{{year}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is another html code (another dropdown)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right myDropdown" role="menu" style="border-radius:0">
  <li data-ng-repeat="year in YearList"><a data-ng-click="SetYear(year,summer2)">{{year}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

That `summer1` and `summer2` is a scope.

Here is my code in controller

```
$scope.SetYear = function(yearValue,myRef){
  myRef = year;
};
```

The logic here is to save `year` to `myRef`.

I tried this one

```
<a data-ng-click="summer1=year">{{year}}</a>
```

but it didn't work..

i try to make that one scope function for all dropdown because i might have many dropdown that will use that function.

Is there any solution to my problem.. and is there any `referencing` in angular?

Comment: why not do `data-ng-click="summer1 = year"`, it will assign it right after the click, no function call involved. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: yes i did it but it didn't work..

Comment: even if `$scope.summer1` is set to `null` before assigning it in view ?

Comment: yes i also did that in the controller but I assigned a value to the scope to test if its working but still didn't work..

Comment: sorry what you need is `data-ng-click="$parent.summer1 = year"`. but thats not a good way. check answer from Polmonite, thats the correct way to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope problem.
In every `ngRepeat` you have a different scope; this means that `summer1` in the first ngRepeat iteration is a different variable than `summer1` outside of the `ngRepeat`.
Probably the simplest way to achieve what you want is to use the variable name as an index:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right myDropdown" role="menu" style="border-radius:0">
  <li data-ng-repeat="year in YearList"><a data-ng-click="SetYear(year,'summer1')">{{year}}</a></li>
</ul>

$scope.SetYear = function(yearValue,myRef){
  $scope[myRef] = year;
};
```

Having `$scope['a-string']` is not good, but you could use another scope variable so you don't get dirty scope, like:

```
$scope.summers = {};
$scope.SetYear = function(yearValue,myRef){
  $scope.summers[myRef] = year;
};
```

And use `$scope.summers.summer1` / `$scope.summers.summer2`.
Or, if you want to do all in the html:

```
<div ng-init="summers={}">
  <h2>Summer 1: {{ summers.summer1 }}</h2>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right myDropdown" role="menu" style="border-radius:0">
    <li data-ng-repeat="year in YearList"><a data-ng-click="summers.summer1=value">{{year}}</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Summer 2: {{ summers.summer2 }}</h2>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right myDropdown" role="menu" style="border-radius:0">
    <li data-ng-repeat="year in YearList"><a data-ng-click="summers.summer2=value">{{year}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```